# Building Near Blockchain Test in Sandbox, unable to generate rocksdb bindings

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am attempting to build NEAR Sandbox for testing my smart contracts.

I follow the guide [here](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/sandbox) .

Currently running : Ubuntu 20.04 , rustc 1.61.0-nightly (6a7055661 2022-02-27).

When I run make a sandbox[image]
I encounter the following error. how would I solve the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install additional library:

`sudo apt install clang` should help.